# Javascript if-else operators why does whats the difference in checking for not equal

Tags: javascript, operators

Ok, I have been on so many pages, and I have used all of the above methods of finding not equal to. However what is peaking my interest currently and has been for a while I guess. Is what is the difference between the following examples, and why does it appear that sometimes only one variation will work over the other in different scenarios, I have been trying to find a solid answer, but its not that easy of a search I suppose.

Anyway In many cases I have had to do something like, because it seems like nothing else will work.

```
if(str == bad_condition)
{
  //ignore
}
else
{
   //code to do something
}
```

Many other times I am doing any one of the following

```
if(!str == bad_condition)
{
   //code to do something
}
```

or

```
if(str != bad_condition)
{
   //code to do something
}
```

or

```
if(str !== bad_condition)
{
   //code to do something
}
```

Now I suppose the ultimate question here, is why do any of the last 3 seem to only work for certain things? Is there a time and place I should either one of them over the other? or is it just some random luck of the draw on my part as I am usually having to deal with someone else's original code base. I'm just curious overall, and Im not trying to spark a debate. I'd just like to seriously know if there is a major difference in the uses of any of the above, and if there is what and why or how.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, so I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those last three are not the same as one another, and you almost certainly don't want to use the first of them. Let's break them down:

---

```
if(!str == bad_condition)
{
   //code to do something
}
```

Don't do that. What happens there is first, the `!str` is evaluated, and then the result of that is compared to `bad_condition`. The result of `!str` will be either `true` or `false`. (It'll be `true` if `str` is `""`, `0`, `null`, `undefined`, or `NaN`; `false` otherwise.) So unless `bad_condition` is `true` or `false`, you don't want to compare `!str` to it, and if `bad_condition` **is** `true` or `false`, there's usually a better way to write the expression.

---

```
if(str != bad_condition)
{
   //code to do something
}
```

This compares `str` to `bad_condition` using ["loose" equality](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3). Loose equality is tricky and the rules for it are complex. `"0" == 0` is `true`, for instance, as are `"" == 0` and `"0" == false`; `"false" == false` is `false`. If you **know** that both `str` and `bad_condition` are the same type, it's fine, but if you don't, you get into type coercion stuff.

---

```
if(str !== bad_condition)
{
   //code to do something
}
```

This compares `str` to `bad_condition` using [*strict* equality](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6). That means no type coercion is done, if `str` and `bad_condition` are not the same type, the condition will always be `false`.

Answer (score 2):

`!=` and `==` go together, they just check for equality not caring for the data type, so the following will happen:

```
console.log([] == ""); //true
```

That's because the **string value** of `[]` evaluates to false (`[].toString()`) - just like the empty string does. (Thanks for Alnitak pointing this out in his comment!)

On the other side `!==` and `===` go together checking for 2 values being identical, so the previous example will evaluate to false. [See here for the "Falsies".](http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/07/27/falsies/)

```
console.log([] === ""); //false
```

The `!value` just negates a variable, so makes expressions that evaluate to `boolean true` false and the other way round.

Comment: `[]` does _not_ evaluate to `false`, it's truthy.  However `[].toString()` _does_, and that's what's used when you do `[] == ""`

Comment: @Alnitak thanks! Included this in my edit, didn't know that before.

Comment: I knew that `[]` was truthy, but it took me a moment to figure out why `!![]` is `true`, but `[] == ""` - it's that implicit call to `.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the first one is clear. str == true is a condition which simply checks if str equals true. In this case true could also be a string.
The 2nd is the negation. That means for example:

```
    var str = true;
    if (str == true) <---- true, cause true == true;
    if (!str == true) <---- false because !str is false and false == true is false;
```

The 3rd means not equal to, meaning:

```
    var str = true;
    if (str != true) <- gives us false because true not equal true is false because it actually is equal.
```

The last one is nearly the same as the 3rd. You use === or !== if you want to compare the value AND the type of the variable.
This means if u have

```
    var str = false;
    if (str === false) <- true, same value and same type (boolean).
```

But:

```
    var str = "false";
    if (str === false) <- false
```

because its the same value but the variable contains a string, not a boolean which is requested by the condition. if the condition would look like:

```
    if (str === "false") it would be true again
```

because the same value + the same type.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `!=` and `!==` is the type checking. For example :

```
true != 0; // true
false != null; // false
false !== null; // true
false != 0; //false
false !== 0; // true
```

But `!str == bad_condition` is weird. I think you want to say `!(str == bad_condition)`. But `!str` is a valid value. `!"test"` is `false` and `!""` is true.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, you also need to know about 'undefined', 'null' and false and how these can give 'seemingly inconsistent' results in a comparison.

This article seems interesting:
http://www.mapbender.org/JavaScript_pitfalls:_null,_false,_undefined,_NaN

Answer (score 0):

`if(str == bad_condition)`

This condition checks if str is equal to bad_condition, it does not check for equivalence, meaning the type of variable is not taken into consideration 1 will be considered the same as "1", returning true.

`if(!str == bad_condition)`

This is simply a negation of the previous if statement, it checks to see if str is not equal to bad_condition.  It can also be written as `if(str != bad_condition)`

`if(str !== bad_condition)`

This condition is checking equivalence, meaning it compares type and value, the expression is also negated.  So the following hold true:

`str = 1, bad_condition = 2` returns true due to negation

`str = 1, bad_condition = "1"` returns true, values are the same, however type is different

`str = 1, bad_condition = 1` returns false since both type and value are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing fundamentally different things here every time!

---

```
str == bad_condition
```

This compares both operands, but does type coercion. So if one operand is a number or string, the other might be converted, which can yield some confusing results.

---

```
!str == bad_condition
```

Here you are doing some type conversion by hand. The `!` operator makes a boolean out of its operand according to some rules.

---

```
str != bad_condition
```

This checks for inequality, but with the same coercion rules as `==`.

---

```
str !== bad_condition
```

Here you check first the types of both operands (no type coercion happens!). If both are of the same type, their contents are checked.

---

So as you see, in every case you compare different stuff. Depending on your specific need I would advise you to use `===` and `!==` as those are the most straight forward comparisons with no type coercions.

Be reminded that JavaScript will compare objects not by contents, but by object references. So `[] === []` yield false, because you create to objects, which do not share the same reference!

As a hint for type coercions take this from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> **Equal (==)**
>
> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.